# StackOverFlowException while trying to generate multiple PDFs using iTextSharp

Tags: itext, stack-overflow

I'm using iTextSharp to generate PDF files from a console application. And I wanted to add a footer to the PDF report. Hence as suggested, I have created a Footer class which inherits PdfPageEventHelper class and overiding the OnEndPage event. Then I have the assigned the instance of this footer class to the PageEvent of my Writer object. Now everything works fine and the PDF file is getting generated.

But I face the problem when I want to generate multiple PDF files in a loop. When I try to create PDF files in a loop, I'm getting StackOverFlowException in the onEndPage event after generating few files. Any suggestions to get rid of this exception? Thanks in Advance.

Regards,

Muthiah

Comment: Please post a SSCCE that reproduces the problem; see http://sscce.org

Comment: As Bruno says, please provide the source. One question ahead, though: you don't add content to the `Document` in `onEndPage`, do you? If you do, that is likely to be the reason.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I'm working on getting a SSCCE by removing all the database connections and stuffs. But after doing those, I'm not able to simulate the issue as there is minimal processing involved. I will get back on this.

Comment: Hi mkl, I'm actually adding the content to the Document in onEndPage. Is there an alternative for that? I'm not familiar. Can you please explain?

Comment: @user3227109 (BTW, please use these at-tags; they make SO inform the mentioned users about your comment). Whenever `onEndPage` is called, this is done either due to an explicit `newPage()` or due to a full page. Obviously adding something to a full page can go wrong. Normally you use direct content access in `onEndPage` (i.e. via `PdfWriter.getDirectContent`). Look at [MovieHistory2.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=103) or [MovieHistory2.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter05&ex=MovieHistory2) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks, @mkl. It worked like a charm. I have removed the Document.Add part and im no longer getting the exception. Thank you so much :)